# Job posted message displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display text message on same page after user submit the form "Your job posted is pending for review". any help would be appreciated. Below is the code from the template.

```
                <?php
                    if( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' ){
                        $button_text = __( 'Update Job', 'jobboard' );
                ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" id="form_type" value="edit_post_job" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $default['post_id'] ); ?>" />
                <?php
                    }else{
                        $button_text = __( 'Post A Job', 'jobboard' );
                ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_type" id="form_type" value="post_job" />
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_current_user_id() ); ?>" />
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-post-resume"><?php echo esc_attr( $button_text ); ?></button>

            </form>
        </div><!-- /.col-md-8 -->

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

redirect your url in same page with querystring then get and echo querystring in your page.

Comment: is it possible you can show me an example on how to redirect url in same page

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg="Project Detail succesfully Submit";
header("location: index.php?msg=Project Detail succesfully Submit");
 <h3><strong> <?php echo $_GET['msg'];?></strong> </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the hidden for field, use this logic

```
    <?
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
    ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $current_url;?>?action=edit&success=1" />
```

Ref: http://cubiq.org/front-end-user-registration-and-login-in-wordpress

So if it is success, then it will redirect to the "redirect_to" else it will display to the error page. So in your theme, get the value by $_GET['success'] == 1 then print your custom message.